# REST API: Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.4

I'm in the middle of finishing a Magento 2 store for a client. The last I had on my to-do list, was connect Magento to their accounting software through the REST API.

However, apparently there's some serious issue when it comes to the REST API in the Magento installation. No matter what I do I'm always given a "*Consumer is not authorized to access %resources*" error, such as:

```
{
    "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Sales::sales"
    }
}
```

POSTMAN Settings:[image]

I'm using an Access Token created through Admin > System > Integrations. The created Integration has resource access set to ALL.

System:

- CentOS 7
- WHM/cPanel
- PHP 7.3.27
- PHP Handler SuPHP
- Magento 2.4.1
- Webserver: Apache (port 8080)
- Cache: Varnish (port 80)
- SSL: Nginx as reverse proxy for SSL (port 443)

Things I've tried based on similar questions:

- Change PHP handler from CGI to SuPHP ([source](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/REST-API-The-consumer-isn-t-authorized-to-access-resources-2-3-1/m-p/387515/highlight/true#M12259))
- Enable individual API resource access instead of setting to 'ALL' ([source](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/REST-API-The-consumer-isn-t-authorized-to-access-resources-2-3-1/m-p/468918/highlight/true#M17033))
- Tested without Varnish between client and server
- Tested without Nginx proxy between client and server

I really can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this? An option would be to do a fresh installation, but that'd be my very last option as I've been working on this Magento environment (theme, thouuuusands of products, ...) for many months.

---

Edit 1: Been digging into this a bit more. Seems like the error is being caused in:
/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Authorization/TokenUserContext.php

(Don't worry, I won't edit vendor files directly ;-))

Lines:

```
    $authorizationHeaderValue = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
    if (!$authorizationHeaderValue) {
        $this->isRequestProcessed = true;
        return;
    }
```

Looks like the Authorization header is missing. They are being set, so I guess something is causing them to be unset or not really being passed to the actual webserver?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me two days, but I've finally figured out (two hours after posting this question -_-). The issue isn't in Magento, Varnish nor Nginx, but is in Apache.

Apparently Apache does not pass the Authorization header by default (for security reasons?). I never knew that was the default behaviour.

Issue solved by adding these lines to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791450/1849527

Comment: It took me two days to find this answer. All the dozens of other things you can tweak in Magento itself are pointless without this. Bravo Jason.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you @Daz!

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.4.4 I had to enable `oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer` (Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens)

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me!